# RestKit: Connect array of id's with entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have JSON response:

```
{ ids: [1,2] }
```

And CoreData entity

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *ids;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet<SomeEntity *> *entities;
```

How to connect ids from array with entities?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<ids_arr> *entities;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add when creating mapping

```
[mapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"entities" 
                 connectedBy:@{@"ids":@"someEntityId"}];
```

Comment: I tried that. But it isn't work. When I try to get entities I get 0 values

Comment: Then check Core Data model. Maybe you forget to create relationship one-to-many or many-to-many?